# Find max value in array of objects containing NaN values

Tags: javascript, max

I have an array of objects and I want to get the max `prevalence` value.

I try this code:

```js
// max of selected vaccine
var ex = [{"name": "a", "prevalence": "NaN"},
 {"name": "a", "prevalence": "5"},
 {"name": "b", "prevalence": "0"},
 {"name": "a", "prevalence": "NaN"},
 {"name": "c", "prevalence": "100"},
 {"name": "c", "prevalence": "20"},
 {"name": "a", "prevalence": "3"}];
console.log('ex:', ex);

var maxPrevalence = d3.max(ex, function(d) {
 if(!isNaN(d.prevalence)) {
  return d.prevalence;
 }
});
console.log('\nmaxPrevalence:', maxPrevalence);
```

```html
<script src='https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js' charset='utf-8'></script>
```

But the result is `5` not `100`.

I don't have to use a d3 function, even pure javascript is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `'NaN'`s are strings, not actual `NaN`s, but regardless, you can `reduce` into `Math.max` while testing the `prevalence` :

```js
var ex=[{"name":"a","prevalence":"NaN"},{"name":"a","prevalence":"5"},{"name":"b","prevalence":"0"},{"name":"a","prevalence":"NaN"},{"name":"c","prevalence":"100"},{"name":"c","prevalence":"20"},{"name":"a","prevalence":"3"}];
const max = Math.max(...ex.reduce(
  (accum, { prevalence }) =>
    isNaN(prevalence) ? accum : [...accum, prevalence],
  [])
);
console.log(max);
```

Comment: That would look nicer, but it would also require iterating over the array twice when it could be done at once with `reduce`. (in the rare case that efficiency matters)

Comment: I disagree. Recreating an array at every iteration is definetly slower than chained native methods, that get optimized by most browsers

Comment: A single map is enough, no need for two loops, filter @JonasW. Look at my answer

Answer (score 1):

Actually `"5"` is bigger than `"100"` as they are compared as strings. You need to make sure that they are compared as numbers:

```
return +d.prevalence;
```

Or you take a slightly easuer approach:

```
  const maxPrevalence = Math.max(...ex.map(d => +d.prevalence).filter(p => !isNaN(p)));
```

Comment: The second returns NaN

Answer (score 1):

You can use Math.max() on the mapped prevalence values:

```js
var ex = [{"name": "a", "prevalence": "NaN"},  {"name": "a", "prevalence": "5"},  {"name": "b", "prevalence": "0"},  {"name": "a", "prevalence": "NaN"},  {"name": "c", "prevalence": "100"},  {"name": "c", "prevalence": "20"},  {"name": "a", "prevalence": "3"}];
let max = Math.max(...ex.map(e => isNaN(e.prevalence) ? Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER : e.prevalence));
console.log(max);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.reduce` & `parseInt` in order to iterate the array, and search for the max value;
The usage of `parseInt` is required because prevalence is a string.

```js
const ex = [{
    "name": "a",
    "prevalence": "NaN"
  },
  {
    "name": "a",
    "prevalence": "5"
  },
  {
    "name": "b",
    "prevalence": "0"
  },
  {
    "name": "a",
    "prevalence": "NaN"
  },
  {
    "name": "c",
    "prevalence": "100"
  },
  {
    "name": "c",
    "prevalence": "20"
  },
  {
    "name": "a",
    "prevalence": "3"
  }
];

const result = ex.reduce((max, current) => {
  const prevalence = parseInt(current.prevalence) || 0;
  return max.prevalence > prevalence ? max : current;
}, {
  prevalence: '0'
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

With d3.js, this code works.
`Number("100")` is number `100`, and `Number('NaN')` is number `NaN`.

```js
// max of selected vaccine
var ex = [{"name": "a", "prevalence": "NaN"}, {"name": "a", "prevalence": "5"}, {"name": "b", "prevalence": "0"}, {"name": "a", "prevalence": "NaN"}, {"name": "c", "prevalence": "100"}, {"name": "c", "prevalence": "20"}, {"name": "a", "prevalence": "3"}];

var maxPrevalence = d3.max(ex, function(d) { return Number(d.prevalence) });
console.log('\nmaxPrevalence:', maxPrevalence);
```

```html
<script src='https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js' charset='utf-8'></script>
```